# Is there a way to view the Android Google Services source code?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-source

I'd like to look at the source code for Google Services (specifically the GoogleMap class, from V2 of the Maps API). I've looked around and haven't been able to find anything.

I know the following:

- The Java API for general Android development can be browsed online: http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/
- The source code for Google Android apps (like Google Maps) is not available: http://source.android.com/faqs.html#how-can-i-get-access-to-the-google-apps-for-android-such-as-maps
- The Eclipse plugin to view Android source code does not include the services source code (as expected).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Since these are proprietary Google classes, I wouldn't expect them to release the source.

Comment: @RaghavSood, I want to look at the code regarding adding Markers to a map, mostly just for curiosity.

Comment: @A--C, I'm not asking for code for Google apps (like Maps, Gmail, etc.), I'm asking about the Google Services API, which is used by Android developers just like the general Android API. Although I agree that I don't think the code's available.

Comment: Found the Javadoc. At least something. Though I can't figure out how to bind it to the Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Google's own applications (Maps, Play Store, Gmail) are not open source and are not part of the Android Open Source Project (AOSP).

Notice that there is a clear distinction in package names:

```
android.*      android core components
com.android.*  internal helper/implementation classes
com.google.*   Google's APIs and apps.
```

Comment: I understand that the code for Google's apps is not available, as I mentioned in my question. The GoogleMap class that I'm interested in is part of the Google Services API, which is available for all Android developers to use. So it seems possible (although unlikely) that the source code is available somehow.